# Issue with dummy network interface

Tags: centos, network-interface

I have a VPS which i need to add a virtual dummy adapter to it to hold a local ip which is a requirment for a software i built.

i have created the needed files which were the dummy.conf and the ifcfg-dummy0 in the proper locations.

the thing is when i do this on a local machine i can see the interface correctly but on the VPS i can't see it.

Note: Using network Manager is not an option

This is done on Centos Linux. Any clue why it is failing on the VPS?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a VPS which i need to add a virtual dummy adapter to it.

No you don't, that misconception is a FAQ.

The only thing you can do with dummy network interfaces is to use them as a placeholder to assign local IP addresses for applications to bind to.

Whatever you need to do with your VPS (you didn't tell us), you need something else.

Please also read up on [XY questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: That is what i need to do. assign an ip to a given interface as a requirment for a custom-built software.

Comment: Then the proper way to debug is: (1) Use `ip` to manually create the dummy interface, run your custom-built software and check that it works as intended (and it's the first time I've actually seen this use case...). (2) Figure out which of the many flavours if networking setup runs on your VPS; with CentOS, probably `systemd`. (3) Use the debugging facilities (of `systemd`, or whatever) to find out why the configuration files you wrote don't get picked up, and/or write configuration files that match what your VPS is using.

Comment: thank you, i will try that and inform you with the results